# TabView in SwiftUI how to deselect all tab items

Tags: swift, swiftui

Is there possibility to deselect all tab items in tab view. 
Or maybe I should somehow change color of selected item to make it look like it is not highlighted

The case that should happen is model.selection >= 5

```
 TabView(selection: $model.selection) {
```

**UPDATE**

More code:

```
struct HamburgerTabView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var model: HamburgerMenuModel

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $model.selection) {
                NavigationView {
                    VStack {
                        Text("Lol").foregroundColor(.black)
                        NavigationLink(destination: Text("NAV").hamburgerButton() ) {
                            Text("Test").foregroundColor(.black)
                        }
                    }
                    .navigationBarTitle("Welcome", displayMode: .inline)
                    .hamburgerButton()


                }
                .tabItem {
                    VStack {
                        Image(systemName: "1.circle")
                        Text("Item 1")
                    }
                }.tag(0)

                NavigationView {
                    Text("Hello World 2").foregroundColor(.red)
                        .navigationBarTitle("Test 2", displayMode: .inline)
                        .hamburgerButton()

                }
                    .tabItem {
                        VStack {
                            Image(systemName: "2.circle")
                            Text("Item 2")
                        }
                    }.tag(1)

                NavigationView {
                    Text("Hello World 3")
                        .navigationBarTitle("Test 3", displayMode: .inline)
                        .hamburgerButton()

                }
                .tabItem {
                        VStack {
                            Image(systemName: "3.circle")
                            Text("Item 3")
                        }
                }.tag(2)

                NavigationView {
                    Text("Hello World 4")
                        .navigationBarTitle("Test 4", displayMode: .inline)
                        .hamburgerButton()

                }
                    .tabItem {
                        VStack {
                            Image(systemName: "4.circle")
                            Text("Item 4")
                        }
                    }.tag(3)

                NavigationView {
                    Text("Hello World 5")
                        .navigationBarTitle("Test 4", displayMode: .inline)
                        .hamburgerButton()

                }
                    .tabItem {
                       VStack {
                            Image(systemName: "5.circle")
                            Text("Item 5")
                        }
                    }.tag(4)
            }
            .onAppear() {
                //UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .red
                //UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = (self.model.selection < 5) ? .green : .red
            }
        .accentColor( (self.model.selection < 5) ? Color.black : Color.black.opacity(0.5))
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share more code from what you have tried?

Comment: I've added some code. but it seems that TabView has very limitted customization options like colors?

Comment: You are probably right. I will try something and if I find something I will get back to you

Comment: I here applied this accent color and then you doesn't see that it is selected. But it seems there is no possibility to apply different backgrounds, foregrounds, tint color on this TabBar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the easiest solution to modify it through an extension:

```
extension UITabBarController {
    override open func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
        appearance.backgroundColor = .white
        appearance.shadowImage = UIImage()
        appearance.shadowColor = .white

        appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.iconColor = .black
        appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]

        appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.iconColor = .red
        appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red]

        tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance
    }
}
```

There should be a better alternative but I could only find modifying some stuff in the constructor of a view, but its limited:

```
    init() {
        UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    }
```

I hope this helps!

**EDIT**

Here a basic custom `TabView` I made from my custom `NavigationView`:

```
struct TabViewItem<E: Comparable, Content>: View where Content: View {

    var id: E
    @Binding var selected: E
    let content: () -> Content

    @inlinable public init(id: E, selected: Binding<E>, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.id = id
        self._selected = selected
        self.content = content
    }


    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            self.content()
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
        .background(self.selected == self.id ? Color(UIColor.systemGray5) : Color.clear)
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
        .onTapGesture {
            self.selected = self.id
        }
    }
}

enum Tab : Int, Comparable {
    public static func < (a: Tab, b: Tab) -> Bool {
        return a.rawValue < b.rawValue
    }
    case Home, World, Settings
}



struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selection: Tab = .Home

    func containedView() -> AnyView {
          switch self.selection {
          case .Home: return AnyView(Text("Home"))
          case .World: return AnyView(Text("World"))
          case .Settings: return AnyView(Text("Settings"))
          }
      }

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                self.containedView()
                Spacer()
                HStack(alignment: .bottom, spacing: 0) {
                    TabViewItem(id: Tab.Home, selected: self.$selection, content: {
                        VStack {
                            Image(systemName: "house")
                            Text("Home")
                        }
                    })
                    TabViewItem(id: Tab.World, selected: self.$selection, content: {
                        VStack {
                            Image(systemName: "globe")
                            Text("World")
                        }
                    })
                    TabViewItem(id: Tab.Settings, selected: self.$selection, content: {
                        VStack {
                            Image(systemName: "gear")
                            Text("Settings")
                        }
                    })
                }.frame(width: proxy.size.width, height: 50)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried it but I cannot modify colours in SwiftUI view, example: to deselect TabItem. Also It doesn't apply to Tab Bar right after application startup, I need to select any Tab Item in order to Tab Bar appearance change.

Comment: Well I guess for that to work you need to wrap `UITabBar` in a `UIViewRepresentable` and make everything custom.

Comment: . I think I set this in viewDidAppear previously but in viewDidLoad it is better as it starts in right colours

Comment: Yeah but I do not know whether wrapping makes sens and whether not to just implement custom TabView with HStack tabback at the bottom. It will be more flexible, and better work with my hamburger menu

Comment: That could be a better solution! I've written a custom `NavigationView` because I couldn't put one in a `.sheet()` and I needed one on an iPad App... sometimes it's just necessary to go custom and with SwiftUI Think it's pretty easy actually!

Comment: Do you know how to set UITabBar appearance  background colour on selected item

Comment: I tried via `appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.badgeBackgroundColor`but that doesn't seam to work, so unfortunately I don't. To answer your question though: A `tabview` always has a selected item as far as I know.

Comment: @MichałZiobro I added a basic example on how a custom `TabView` could look like.

Comment: Thanks I will to this, I think your example help me with implementation of this custom Tab/HamburgerMenu. Do you think it is possible to implement your containedView more like TabView { View1().tabItem() View2().tabItem() View3().tabItem()  } or  TabView(tabs: { TabViewItem(), TabViewItem(), TabViewItem() }, hamburgerLinks { SideViewItem(), SideViewItem(), SideViewItem()   } ) { View1() View2() View3()  }

I think it would be then very reusable component.

Comment: Probably yes, but since I am also pretty new to SwiftUI and Swift in general I need to learn more before attempting this.